# htop command displays 996GB instead of 1024GB for RAM

Tags: debian, memory, ram, htop, free

I have a little issue that I can't understand.

I have 8x128GB sticks of RAM, which makes 1024GB of RAM.

But the command `htop` displays `996G` and not `1024G` as expected.

You can see the following illustration below :

[image: htop image]

How to interpret this result ?

**UPDATE:** This is a strange result since on my MacOS Macbook, I have
officially 64GB of RAM and when I type the command htop, I get the following result :

[image: htop macos image]

As you can see, it displays all the amount of official memory, i.e 64GB of RAM unlike to Debian 10 Linux. I don't understand this difference.

Could anyone explain me the reason ?

Comment: I believe this value is the same as *MemTotal* from `/proc/meminfo`. According to `man proc`, *MemTotal* is "Total usable RAM (i.e., physical RAM minus a few reserved bits and the kernel binary code)".

Comment: @berndbausch . I don't understand the "RAM minus a few reserved bits and the kernel binary" : normally, it should display 8*128 GB, i.e the total quantity of sticks, shouldn't it ?

Comment: If I am right, it displays the amount of memory that you can use. That is your RAM minus a few reserved bits and the kernel. If you want the amount of installed memory, use a tool like dmidecode, which queries the BIOS. Note that your Mac doesn't run on Linux.

Comment: @berndbausch . Thanks, I am going to try. Did you see my **UPDATE** and the difference between MacOS and Debian ?

Comment: Yes. MacOS is based on a BSD UNIX (not sure which), whereas Linux isn't.

Comment: any OS can suffer from this if there are some unusable memory regions due to devices that can't be remapped or similar things: [Why is usable RAM less than total RAM?](https://superuser.com/q/54056/241386), [Why do my OSes only recognize 3 GiB of RAM?](https://superuser.com/q/591793/241386), [Windows detects only 4.75GB of 8GB RAM](https://superuser.com/q/764376/241386). You can never use all the available memory, there are always at least some unusable pages. The page zero is usually not available in all OSes to catch null pointer accesses

Comment: see [Getting memory map of every device in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10334596/995714). Look at the map and you'll know why some address ranges weren't available. You can then reconfigure it to maximize the usable memory